# Redux Toolkit RTK Query - Difference between useGetDomainsQuery VS api.endpoints.getDomains.initiate(args)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query, reselect

I want to make an API call with some params, and use the selectors to get that values in my components
I am getting data in below implementation

```
const { data, isLoading, isFetching, error } = useGetDomainsQuery({
    search: search || '',
    status: status || '',
    page_number: pageNo,
    page_size: pageRow,
  });
```

whereas, I am not getting data in selector

```
dispatch(
    api.endpoints.getDomains.initiate({
      search: search || '',
      status: status || '',
      page_number: pageNo,
      page_size: pageRow,
    }),
  );
```

Selector:-

```
export const selectDomainsResult = api.endpoints.getDomains.select();

const selectDomainsData = createSelector(
  selectDomainsResult,
  (domainsResult) => domainsResult.data, 
);


export const {
  selectAll: selectAllDomains,
  selectById: selectDomainById,
  selectIds: selectDomainIds,
} = domainsAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) =>
     selectDomainsData(state) ?? initialState,
);
```

and using my selector like this

```
const domains = useSelector(selectAllDomains);
```

this implementation always gets uninitialised and returns empty array users: []

Answer (score 0):

The selector you have created with `api.endpoints.getDomains.select()` will give you the cache entry for calling `initiate()` or `initiate(undefined)` but not `initiate(something)` - for that you would have to use `select(something)`.